# Xml read using libxml2 library

Tags: c++, xml, xml2

I have a XML file as below

```
<root>
<Radii1 VT = "121212 121212"/>
</root>
```

I am trying to read the xml using libxml2 library.

```
cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
while (cur != NULL) {
if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"Radii1"))){

    }

cur = cur->next;
}
```

Now , my problem is if i am printing the cur->name, first it is giving me text then next time it will give me Radii1 and again next time will give text and then will exit the code.

I am not sure why that is happening is the format of the xml not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML format is correct, but a node is not just an XML entity. You're seeing nodes in the XML document that represent text portions of the document; namely the whitespace -- and specifically the newlines -- between the XML entities.

What you want to do is examine the value in cur->type, whether it's an `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`, an `XML_TEXT_NODE`; or any one of various other kinds of XML nodes, and decide what you want to do with them.

And if you are searching for a particular attribute, like "VT", it would be one of the child `XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE`s of the `Radii1` `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`.

Comment: So what basically i should do is first check if the current node type is XML_ELEMENT_NODE then i can directly use the xmlGetProp to get the value of the VT attribute? or do i still go ahead and have to check whether it is XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE ?..and if so how i can check that..

Comment: Once you get to `Radii1` node, you can get attributes using [`xmlGetProp`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlGetProp) function.